# How to upload a Binary STL to Windchill using REST API in python?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests, binaryfiles

I have been able following the Windchill support link https://www.ptc.com/en/support/article/cs330694
to upload an ASCII file (including an STL file). However, when I try to upload a binary file, the file which gets uploaded to the Windchill is corrupted.

I am using Requests python module for http client. This is a multipart/form POST.
I read the Binary stream using this code:

`with open(files[0], 'rb') as f: content = f.read()`

Then simply I form the payload "Body" of the request following the instruction in the above link.
where I simply add the content to the string using the format(entry1, entry2,..)
entry2 = content

I tried to trim the leading b' and tail '
That resulted in the following:
When I compare reading the original STL file to the uploaded one I get this difference for reading the only 100 first bytes:

original:
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbc\x91\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\xcd\xec\xd7C'
uploaded:
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
so there are two backslashes \ instead of only one backslash \

Comment: The tag [tag:STL] is not about Python and STL files

Comment: this is the line of python code I use:
`r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=(username, password))` 
the payload is simply formed following the link I shared above. something strange from the requests library or python string automatically adds a backslash. changing for example \x00 to \\x00

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. Apparently, Windchill REST API Binary(bytes) stream are read as plain text. Therefore, to store/upload a binary file to the windchill via REST API the octet-stream must be encoded into string from bytes using encode('latin1') as the only encoding that will work not base64 intermediate. It wants a mapping from unsigned char (0-255) to a latin character. the UTF-8 does not work because it's not a single byte mapping.
After checking the content of the uploaded file I realized that the data is always loaded as is into a plain text file. That's what confused me initially into thinking that it was a problem of a double backslash vs a single slash.

python code:

```
   with open(files[0], 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()

    content = content.decode('latin-1')
```